# KVM booting off-image kernel and existing partition

Tags: kvm-virtualization, lvm, libvirt

I am in the process of switching from Xen to qemu-kvm. My current Xen installation has a number of LVM volumes each with a partition (rather than a full disk image). In Xen, I start each VM with a configuration like so:

```
kernel = "/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.18-128.4.1.el5xen"
ramdisk = "/boot/initrd-xen-2.6.18-128.4.1.el5xen"
disk   = [ 'phy:/dev/vmdata/vm-standalone,sda1,w' ]
```

I now want to reuse these VMs but start them under kvm instead. It seems that virt-install `--import` would let me do this, using `--boot kernel=<kernel>,initrd=<initrd>`, but I don't see how I can instruct virt-install to attach the existing volume as boot/root file system. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answers from dynasy and Jared are both pointing in the right direction, but leaves a bit unexplained.

The short answer to my question is that virt-install is perfectly capable of supplying a partition to the booting system. In fact, for block devices, it doesn't care and just pass it on to qemu that sets it up like a block device. Then the kernel uses /dev/sda (rather than /dev/sda1) as root file system.

The command line for achieving this looks like this:

```
virt-install --name nic 
  --ram 512 
  --disk /dev/vg_ext/nic-standalone
  --disk /dev/vg_ext/nic-swap
  --network bridge=br0
  --boot kernel=/boot/vmlinuz,initrd=/boot/initramfs.img,kernel_args="console=ttyS0 root=/dev/sda" 
  --serial=pty
```

In order to make this work, I had to modify /etc/fstab on nic-standalone so that it pointed to the correct root file system and swap partition (/dev/sda, /dev/sdb). Kernel and initrd above are standard CentOS 6 stuff. (There may be various performance parameters/tweaks desired as well, I just haven't gotten that far yet.)

Answer (score 3):

I've been researching this topic as well and just posted a somewhat similar question, but with a different scope:  [KVM/qemu - use LVM volumes directly without image file?](https://serverfault.com/questions/410210)

For your particular question, does this work:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/QEMU#By_specifying_kernel_and_initrd_manually

In particular, `-append root=/dev/sda /dev/sda3`.  I haven't tried it myself, but it seems like it should do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a new VM in `virt-manager` or via `virsh` with similar parameters as the Xen one (memory, CPU etc), and when asked to create virtual disks for it, point to the existing Xen disks.

You might need to adjust `fstab` a bit, to point to `/dev/vdX` instead of `xvdX` (or whatever Xen uses)

If you want a really nice move procedure that will take care of everything for you, you can use `virt-v2v`.